# Is there any other configuration to be done left over along with Livy server(livy.conf)?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, dockerfile, livy

I have setup the docker for the hadoop yarn, and I am trying to setup the livy apache server to make API call's for job submissions.

The logs below represents that the livy-server starts for certain time and stops automatically

```
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Welcome to
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:       ____              __
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:      / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:     _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:    /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.1
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:       /_/
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Using Scala version 2.11.8, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_222
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Branch
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Compiled by user felixcheung on 2017-11-24T23:19:45Z
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Revision
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Url
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Type --help for more information.
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO recovery.StateStore$: Using BlackholeStateStore for recovery.
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO sessions.BatchSessionManager: Recovered 0 batch sessions. Next session id: 0
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO sessions.InteractiveSessionManager: Recovered 0 interactive sessions. Next session id: 0
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO sessions.InteractiveSessionManager: Heartbeat watchdog thread started.
19/08/17 07:09:35 INFO util.log: Logging initialized @1944ms
19/08/17 07:09:36 INFO server.Server: jetty-9.3.24.v20180605, build timestamp: 2018-06-05T17:11:56Z, git hash: xxx0x0x0xx00xxxx0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0xxxx
19/08/17 07:09:36 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3543df7d{/,file:///livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/bin/src/main/org/apache/livy/server,AVAILABLE}
19/08/17 07:09:36 INFO server.AbstractNCSARequestLog: Opened /livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/logs/2019_08_17.request.log
19/08/17 07:09:36 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@686449f9{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{x.x.x.x:8080}
19/08/17 07:09:36 INFO server.Server: Started @2304ms
19/08/17 07:09:36 INFO server.WebServer: Starting server on http://x.x.x.x:8080
19/08/17 07:10:01 INFO server.LivyServer: Shutting down Livy server.
19/08/17 07:10:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3543df7d{/,file:///livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/bin/src/main/org/apache/livy/server,UNAVAILABLE}
19/08/17 07:10:01 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Stopped ServerConnector@686449f9{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{x.x.x.x:8080}
```

I have provided the livy.conf mentioning the server ip and server port for the livy to run on. As am trying spark yarn submit I have done their setup too, I have attached the files below

docker-compose

```
version: "2"

services:
 livy:
  image: namenode/hadoopspark:2.2.1
  command: /livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/bin/livy-server start
  network_mode: "host"
  ports:
   - 8080:8080


#####################BASE DOCKERFILE#################

FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DAEMON_RUN=true
ENV SPARK_VERSION=2.2.1
ENV HADOOP_VERSION=2.7
ENV SPARK_HOME=/spark
ENV HADOOP_HOME=/hadoop

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y software-properties-common openssh-server net-tools curl nano vim wget ca-certificates jq gnupg unzip

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk \
 supervisor

RUN ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN wget https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/incubator/livy/0.6.0-incubating/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin.zip \
 && unzip apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin.zip \
 && mkdir -p livy \
 && mv apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin /livy

RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz \
 &&  tar -xzf spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz \
 &&  mv spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION} /spark

RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.7.3/hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz \
 && tar -xzvf hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz \
 && mv hadoop-2.7.3 /hadoop

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/hadoop/etc/hadoop

RUN echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/ \
export HADOOP_HOME=/hadoop \
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/hadoop/etc/hadoop \
export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS='"-p 22"' \
" >> /hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

ENV PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
ENV PATH=$PATH:/hadoop/bin:/hadoop/sbin


################NAMENODE DOCKERFILE####################

FROM base/hadoopspark:2.2.1

COPY conf/* /tmp/

RUN cp /tmp/hdfs-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml && \
    cp /tmp/core-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml && \
    cp /tmp/mapred-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml && \
    cp /tmp/yarn-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml && \
    cp /tmp/hdfs-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf/ && \
    cp /tmp/core-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf/ && \
    cp /tmp/mapred-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf/ && \
    cp /tmp/yarn-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf/ && \
    cp /tmp/spark-defaults.conf $SPARK_HOME/conf/ && \
    cp /tmp/livy.conf /livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/conf

COPY Docker_WordCount_Spark-1.0.jar /opt/Docker_WordCount_Spark-1.0.jar
COPY sample.txt /opt/sample.txt

#RUN hdfs dfs -put /opt/Docker_WordCount_Spark-1.0.jar Docker_WordCount_Spark-1.0.jar
#RUN hdfs dfs -put /opt/sample.txt sample.txt

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/hadoop/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

RUN sudo service ssh restart
RUN sudo /hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format

EXPOSE 8998 8080
```

Need help whether any other to start livy server. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Docker requires command(s) to keep running in the foreground. Otherwise, it thinks that application is stopped and it shutdown the container. As livy server startup  script runs in background processes, and no other foreground process triggered later, that`s why container exits when script ends. You can solve this many ways, the simple solution is add the following command in **Dockerfile** to start the liver server ( remove command from docker-compose.yml)

```
CMD /livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/bin/livy-server start && /bin/bash
```

The livy server docker image is:

```
FROM base/hadoopspark:2.2.1

COPY conf/* /tmp/

ENV SPARK_HOME=/spark
ENV HADOOP_HOME=/hadoop

RUN cp /tmp/hdfs-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml && \
    cp /tmp/core-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml && \
    cp /tmp/mapred-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml && \
    cp /tmp/yarn-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml && \
    cp /tmp/hdfs-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf/ && \
    cp /tmp/core-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf/ && \
    cp /tmp/mapred-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf/ && \
    cp /tmp/yarn-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf/ && \
    cp /tmp/spark-defaults.conf $SPARK_HOME/conf/ && \
    cp /tmp/livy.conf /livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/conf

COPY Docker_WordCount_Spark-1.0.jar /opt/Docker_WordCount_Spark-1.0.jar
COPY sample.txt /opt/sample.txt

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/hadoop/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

RUN sudo service ssh restart
RUN sudo /hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format

ENV PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$PATH

EXPOSE 8998 8080

CMD /livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/bin/livy-server start && /bin/bash
```

Comment: I tried it. It still exits with this result of - Log attached: `Creating namenode_livy_1
Attaching to namenode_livy_1
livy_1  | starting /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java  -cp /livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/jars/*:/livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/conf:/hadoop/etc/hadoop: org.apache.livy.server.LivyServer, logging to /livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/logs/livy--server.out
namenode_livy_1 exited with code 0`

Comment: Please use tty option, I have added the docker-compose in another answer with code format

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add **tty** parameter to docker compose and run the container in detach mode.

```
version: "2"

services:
 livy:
  image: namenode/hadoopspark:2.2.1
  command: /livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/bin/livy-server start
  network_mode: "host"
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
  tty:  true
```

Start the docker container with 
**docker-compose up -d**

Comment: still I face the same issue. The issue seems to be with Livy server itself which am not sure about?. I have tried both the detached mode and undetached still the container gets exited. The Livy server shuts down on its own after getting started and running for just a second which is really fishy!

Comment: I suggest, tail the livy-server logs so that you can able to see the reason also container is in foreground process to debug the issue.  CMD["/livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/bin/livy-server start; tail -f /livy/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/logs/livy--server.out ; /bin/bash"]

Comment: Yes, as I entered exited container and tailed  logs -

Comment: As I couldn't attach the log in the comment you can view the log which is already in the question. They are similar the same thing happens now

Comment: If you have time. Can you please try this out in your local?

Comment: I run the docker image locally in my machine, as container exited immediately bcz there is no foreground process to hold container. After adding tty: true in docker compose, can able to connect livy UI http://localhost:8080 and container is running until I stop or manually killed.  Please try to run the livy server locally without docker container with same approach to debug this issue.